# Angular2 ag-grid-enterprise project having issue while placing License Key

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm having license for ag-grid-enterprise version but i didn;t get how to place it and how to import the enterprise in my angular2 project.

i'm trying to place license in main.ts file with licenseManager
and also place the version of enterprise in package.json and systemjs.config.json

but i'm getting error as [image: click here to see image]

systemjs.config.js:

```
'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid',
'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
'ag-grid-enterprise': 'node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise'
'ag-grid': {
   defaultExtension: "js"
 },
 'ag-grid-ng2': {
   defaultExtension: "js"
 },
 'ag-grid-enterprise': {
   defaultExtension: "js"
 }
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "ag-grid": "7.1.x",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "7.1.x",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "7.1.x",

    "@angular/common": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.x",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.x",
    "rxjs": "5.0.x",
    "zone.js": "0.7.x",
    "core-js": "2.4.x",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "2.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.3",
    "rimraf": "2.5.x",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.15.33",
    "copyfiles": "1.0.x",
    "ncp": "2.0.x",

    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-systemjs": "0.16.0",
    "protractor": "4.0.13",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
```

main.ts

```
import {LicenseManager} from "ag-grid-enterprise/main";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("your license key");
```

"Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1039:29) []
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [ => ]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) []
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid as "ag-grid" from http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/enterpriseMenu.js
    at addToError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:123:78) []
    at linkSetFailed (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:726:21) []
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:522:9 []
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43) [ => ]
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:535:57 []
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [ => ]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:433:35) []
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25) []"

Comment: try to refer to real ag-grid main js file. `packages: {
                // ...
                'ag-grid': {
                    main: 'main.js'
                }
            }`

Comment: @TiepPhan means `'ag-grid': {
   main: "main.js"
 },`

Comment: thanx @TiepPhan now it is working

Comment: yeap, change session packages to something like this https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example/blob/master/systemjs_aot/systemjs.config.js#L28

Comment: Hi - if you're an enterprise customer you should post on the members forum: https://ag-grid.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=5 - you'll get a very quick turn around in support there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to refer to real ag-grid main js file

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        // angular libraries

        // ag libraries
        'ag-grid-ng2': 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
        'ag-grid': 'node_modules/ag-grid',
        'ag-grid-enterprise': 'node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise'
    },
    packages: {
       // code ...
       'ag-grid': {
            main: 'main.js'
        }
    }
});
```